# System Architecture design

Tags: architecture, system

I am hard time understanding the concept of system complexity.
Can any one help me understand the relationship between the complexity of overall system and the complexity of all the subsystems?

> Expressed as C(S) = C(SS1) + C(SS2)+..C(SSn)
>
> C(S): Complexity of entire system
>
> C(SS1): Complexity of simple subsystem

Comment: "Expressed as C(S) = C(SS1) + C(SS2)+..C(SSn)"  That would largely be false.  Components interact.  The complexity is not a linear combination at all.  Where have you seen this?  Why ask?  What do you want to know?

Comment: @S.Lott I disagree,  the formula he stated is correct.  Just because components interact, does not mean their complexity increases.    The equation is just trying to show that you can breakup the complexity in  "chunks," and the sum of those chunks is equal to the whole.

Comment: @Nix: The overall complexity is rarely a linear combination of the parts.  The COCOMO model, for example, shows that the effort grows exponentially.  Effort must be based on something like complexity. (COCOMO doesn't measure that directly, so it's hard to be perfectly sure.)  A claim of linear growth needs to be backed up with some quotes or references or links or something.

Comment: Agreed, but think of it as a system that is "as is."  We can take the C(S) complexity for the entire system.  Alternatively we can that the same system, breaking it up into pieces SS* and calculating each systems complexity, when you add them back together you will get C(S).  The equation doesn't imply any relation in complexities.

Comment: @Nix: "The equation doesn't imply any relation in complexities"?  It clearly states the overall complex is a linear sum.  Which, I'm pretty sure, can't possibly be true except in the rare case that each component is absolutely independent.  That is, each component is a distinct vector in some vector space of complexity.

Comment: @S.Lott You are reading too far into it, the equation is simply just aggregating complexities.  Its not telling you that if you add another SSn that it will increase linearly.

Comment: @Nix: I'm reading the equation as written.  It says linear.  If you want it to not say linear, then use the "Union" operator or something else.

Comment: @S.Lott where does it say linear?

Comment: @Nix: "+" is linear combination of vectors.

Comment: Hmm, never knew that "+" always meant linear combination of vectors... I was taught it meant addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that equation is trying to say is that a systems complexity is the sum of its parts.

So

> C(S) = X (overall complexity)

Now break it up into distinct sub systems

> C(S) = C(SS1) + C(SS2)+..C(SSn)

Calculate each systems complexity:

> C(SS1) = A
>
> C(SS2) = B
>
> C(SSn) = n

If we add those together it will be the same as C(S) aka:

> X = A + B + ..n
>
> C(S) = X =  A + B + .. + n =  C(SS1) + C(SS2)+..C(SSn)

Please make sure you note what S.Lott said above, that the equation by no means implies complexity as a linear relationship of a system to its subsystems, aka the system complexity doesn't necessarily grow linearly as you add new components.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but for future reference I strong encourage you to take a look at Roger Sessions' work on complexity; he's also done a lot on measuring the complexity of SOA based systems in particular.

As far as measuring complexity goes - check out page 8 of this PDF: http://www.objectwatch.com/whitepapers/ITComplexityWhitePaper.pdf